# I have a M1 Pro MBP and was trying to upgrade my default Python from V3.8.8 to V3.11.1 but now can no longer "see" any packages in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

In changing the symlink to V3.11.1, I've "lost" access to all Python packages installed under 3.8.8. Aanconda can't find any modules either, either under 3.8 or 3.11 and won't let me reinstall Anaaconda.

At the terminal prompt, I can get to V3.11.1 via Python3 command (not Python) and can see a list of modules but none of the packages previously installed. Tried to reinstall Anaconda but the installer says to upgrade instead. When I try to upgrade at the system prompt, "conda" isn't recognized.

I'm know my references are all messed up but not sure how to get my environment working. Appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: Most Python packages are specific to the version - you need to reinstall them for 3.11. If using Conda, create a new environment rather than reinstall Anaconda. Furthermore, Anaconda doesn't even ship for 3.11 yet (see [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda/files)). Probably will need to be using `conda-forge` channel (and note that they haven't officially finished migrating all packages to 3.11 either).

Comment: Thanks - Anaconda ships with 3.9; would it be better to set 3.9 as the default or 3.10 (I show many packages  running under my 3.10 install)?

Comment: Anaconda should allow you to upgrade the base to 3.10, if that’s what you’re after: `conda install -n base anaconda python=3.10`